# Prove that any dihedral group can be generated by symmetry and reflections.

Tags: group-theory, dihedral-groups

One definition of a dihedral group $D_n$ is

$$\langle s,r : s^2=r^2=(sr)^n=1 \rangle.$$

where $s$ is a symmetry along an axis and $r$ is a rotation of $2\pi/n$. I was just thinking this is how dihedral groups are defined but is it possible to show that the dihedral groups can be generated by two generators of order 2?

Comment: Oh right, I will change it to degree.

Comment: Oh sorry, it was correct, I wrote something stupid.

Comment: In that definition of $D_n$, both generators $r$ and $s$ are reflections, obviously of order 2. It is not $r$ but $sr$ that is the rotation of order $n$.

Answer (score 0):

Rotation by 2*pi/n generates all rotations, so it is left to prove that we can obtain also all symmetries.
Check what is $rsr^{-1},r^{2}sr^{-2},r^{3}sr^{-3}$,... up to $r^{n-1}sr^{-(n-1)}$